# How to change into italic style one letter in R plot without adding a space

Tags: r, plot

I have almost done what I need that is basically having "q" and "Å" in italic in the x-axis label. However, I want to avoid the space before and after the "Å"... It is probably a silly question but I have been trying to remove the "~" and something else without success. Where am I wrong? Basically, the result should be:
"Scattering factor, *q*(1/*Å*)" instead of "Scattering factor, *q*(1/ *Å* )"

```
plot(1, 1, xlab= expression("Scattering factor,"~italic(q)~"(1/"~italic(Å)~")"))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
plot(1, 1, xlab= expression("Scattering factor,"~italic(q)~paste("(1/",italic(Å),")")))
```