# Italic letters in generated axis tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath, italic

I have an issue creating axis tick labels that combine italic letters and input of variables.
Simply said, I want to call variables and insert text such as *n* = 1 below each label.

Here's an example with everything but the italic *n*:

```
require(ggplot2)

mpg$class <- as.factor(mpg$class)
counts <- rep(1:7, 1)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(levels(mpg$class), "\nn = ", counts, sep = ""))
```

[image]

My first thought was to use the Unicode for an italic N, like I've done for superscript numbers in the past. But for some reason, the letter is too small & stylistically mismatched with the rest of the text. More importantly, in my real use-case, all Unicode characters for italic n appear to render out of alignment, depressed somewhere halfway between normal and subscript.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(levels(mpg$class), "\n\U1D45B = ", counts, sep = ""))
```

[image]

So, I found the `plotmath` function `~italic(x)` could be used to italicize letters. However, there's a clear and unexpected failure when I incorporate it in the `paste()` line for the x-axis tick labels. Note that the function does work in `xlab()`

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() + xlab(~italic("n")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(levels(mpg$class), "\n", ~italic("n"), " = ", counts, sep = ""))
```

[image]

I have searched StackOverflow for similar cases. However, none of them need to call for variables:

[Add greek letters to axis tick labels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068217/add-greek-letters-to-axis-tick-labels-in-r)

[Changing one character in axis tick labels to italic while keeping multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067258/changing-one-character-in-axis-tick-labels-to-italic-while-keeping-multiple-line)

[How to change into italic style one letter in R plot without adding a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297326/how-to-change-into-italic-style-one-letter-in-r-plot-without-adding-a-space)

[How to italicize part (one or two words) of an axis title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555531/how-to-italicize-part-one-or-two-words-of-an-axis-title?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I have tried understanding how to use `expression()` and `bquote()` while being able to call variables, but I have been unable to produce anything functional.

At this point, any help is very appreciated!

Comment: wb `parse(text=sprintf('atop("%s", italic(n)==%s)', levels(mpg$class), counts))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days, you can use the ggtext package to style your text with some markdown/html decorations.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
#> Warning: package 'ggtext' was built under R version 4.1.1

mpg$class <- as.factor(mpg$class)
counts <- rep(1:7, 1)

ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = paste0(levels(mpg$class), "<br><i>n = ", counts, "</i>")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! I previously failed using ggtext, but updating its dependencies and following this example solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

editing the answer of teunbrand above, to only italicize the `n` without italicizing the count itself: is by adding `</i>` in the end of the `"<br><i>n = "` to become `"<br><i>n </i>= "`

label will be:
`paste0(levels(mpg$class), "<br><i>n</i> = ", counts)`

instead of:
`paste0(levels(mpg$class), "<br><i>n = ", counts, "</i>")`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

mpg$class <- as.factor(mpg$class)
counts <- rep(1:7, 1)

# italicized count
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = paste0(levels(mpg$class), "<br><i>n = ", counts,"</i>")
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())


# not italicized count
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = paste0(levels(mpg$class), "<br><i>n</i> = ", counts) 
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

Italicized count
[image]

Not italicized count
[image]