# Italic font in one scale label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, scale, italic

I want to put one label of x axis with italics font with this code:

```
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("factor1", "<i>factor2</i>"))+
```

But it doesn't work.
Do I need to install some package?
Is there an alternative way to do so?

Comment: To style your axis labels using HTML I would suggest to have a look at the `ggtext` package. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69591775/12993861

Comment: Try: scale_x_discrete(labels = c("factor1", expression(italic("factor2")))) or for both: scale_x_discrete(labels = c(expression(italic("factor1")), expression(italic("factor2"))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to overwrite the labels as such:

```r
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("factor1", "factor2" = expression(italic(factor2))))+
```